# ifstream reading file...help needed

Tags: c++, ifstream

Sorry for the last thread and not responding; I went to bed and forgot to post the full code; though I am still sorry for not answering.

The problem rests in the function "bool readFile()" and will crash my program if used a 2nd time.

I do not know how to fix this crash and would appreciate help on editing my code.

Thanks.

```
#include "basic.h"
#include "file.h"
#include "initialize.h"
#include "macros.h"
#include "values.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>

#pragma region Global Variables

EXTERN_C IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;

static enum StringValue { evS1, evS2, evS3, evS4, evS5, evS6, evS7, evS8, evS9, evS10, evS11, evS12, evS13, evS14, evS15, evS16, evS17, evS18, evS19, evS20, evS21, evS22, evS23, evS24, evS25, evS26, evS27, evS28, evS29, evS30, evS31, evS32, evS33, evS34, evS35, evS36, evS37, evS38, evS39, evS40, evS41, evS42, evS43, evS44, evS45};

static std::map<std::string, StringValue> s_mapStringValues;

static char Input[_MAX_PATH];

string Line[4];

int Temporary;

#pragma endregion

string retrievePath()
{
    LPTSTR strDLLPath1 = new TCHAR[_MAX_PATH];
    ::GetModuleFileName((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase, strDLLPath1, _MAX_PATH);
    string::size_type pos = string(strDLLPath1).find_last_of("\\/");
    std:: string strRet = string(strDLLPath1).substr(0, pos);
    return strRet;
}

void initializeKeys()
{
    s_mapStringValues["0"] = evS1;
    s_mapStringValues["1"] = evS2;
    s_mapStringValues["2"] = evS3;
    s_mapStringValues["3"] = evS4;
    s_mapStringValues["4"] = evS5;
    s_mapStringValues["5"] = evS6;
    s_mapStringValues["6"] = evS7;
    s_mapStringValues["7"] = evS8;
    s_mapStringValues["8"] = evS9;
    s_mapStringValues["9"] = evS10;

    s_mapStringValues["A"] = evS11;
    s_mapStringValues["B"] = evS12;
    s_mapStringValues["C"] = evS13;
    s_mapStringValues["D"] = evS14;
    s_mapStringValues["E"] = evS15;
    s_mapStringValues["F"] = evS16;
    s_mapStringValues["G"] = evS17;
    s_mapStringValues["H"] = evS18;
    s_mapStringValues["I"] = evS19;
    s_mapStringValues["J"] = evS20;

    s_mapStringValues["K"] = evS21;
    s_mapStringValues["L"] = evS22;
    s_mapStringValues["M"] = evS23;
    s_mapStringValues["N"] = evS24;
    s_mapStringValues["O"] = evS25;
    s_mapStringValues["P"] = evS26;
    s_mapStringValues["Q"] = evS27;
    s_mapStringValues["R"] = evS28;
    s_mapStringValues["S"] = evS29;
    s_mapStringValues["T"] = evS30;

    s_mapStringValues["U"] = evS31;
    s_mapStringValues["V"] = evS32;
    s_mapStringValues["W"] = evS33;
    s_mapStringValues["X"] = evS34;
    s_mapStringValues["Y"] = evS35;
    s_mapStringValues["Z"] = evS36;

    s_mapStringValues["SHIFT"] = evS37;
    s_mapStringValues["CTRL"] = evS38;
    s_mapStringValues["ALT"] = evS39;
    s_mapStringValues["PAGE UP"] = evS40;
    s_mapStringValues["PAGE DOWN"] = evS41;
    s_mapStringValues["END"] = evS42;
    s_mapStringValues["HOME"] = evS43;
    s_mapStringValues["INS"] = evS44;
    s_mapStringValues["DEL"] = evS45;
}

void mapKeys()
{
    switch(s_mapStringValues[Input])
    {
      case evS1:
          Temporary = 0x30;
        break;
      case evS2:
          Temporary = 0x31;
        break;
      case evS3:
          Temporary = 0x32;
        break;
      case evS4:
          Temporary = 0x33;
        break;
      case evS5:
          Temporary = 0x34;
        break;
      case evS6:
          Temporary = 0x35;
        break;
      case evS7:
          Temporary = 0x36;
        break;
      case evS8:
          Temporary = 0x37;
        break;
      case evS9:
          Temporary = 0x38;
        break;
      case evS10:
          Temporary = 0x39;
        break;
      case evS11:
          Temporary = 0x41;
        break;
      case evS12:
          Temporary = 0x42;
        break;
      case evS13:
          Temporary = 0x43;
        break;
      case evS14:
          Temporary = 0x44;
        break;
      case evS15:
          Temporary = 0x45;
        break;
      case evS16:
          Temporary = 0x46;
        break;
      case evS17:
          Temporary = 0x47;
        break;
      case evS18:
          Temporary = 0x48;
        break;
      case evS19:
          Temporary = 0x49;
        break;
      case evS20:
          Temporary = 0x4A;
        break;
      case evS21:
          Temporary = 0x4B;
        break;
      case evS22:
          Temporary = 0x4C;
        break;
      case evS23:
          Temporary = 0x4D;
        break;
      case evS24:
          Temporary = 0x4E;
        break;
      case evS25:
          Temporary = 0x4F;
        break;
      case evS26:
          Temporary = 0x50;
        break;
      case evS27:
          Temporary = 0x51;
        break;
      case evS28:
          Temporary = 0x52;
        break;
      case evS29:
          Temporary = 0x53;
        break;
      case evS30:
          Temporary = 0x54;
        break;
      case evS31:
          Temporary = 0x55;
        break;
      case evS32:
          Temporary = 0x56;
        break;
      case evS33:
          Temporary = 0x57;
        break;
      case evS34:
          Temporary = 0x58;
        break;
      case evS35:
          Temporary = 0x59;
        break;
      case evS36:
          Temporary = 0x5A;
        break;
      case evS37:
          Temporary = 0x10;
        break;
      case evS38:
          Temporary = 0x11;
        break;
      case evS39:
          Temporary = 0x12;
        break;
      case evS40:
          Temporary = 0x21;
        break;
      case evS41:
          Temporary = 0x22;
        break;
      case evS42:
          Temporary = 0x23;
        break;
      case evS43:
          Temporary = 0x24;
        break;
      case evS44:
          Temporary = 0x2D;
        break;
      case evS45:
          Temporary = 0x2E;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
}

bool readFile()
{
    int lineCounter = 0;

    string fileLine;

    string configurationLocation = retrievePath() + "\\configuration";

    ifstream configurationFile;

    configurationFile.open(configurationLocation + ".config");

    if (!configurationFile)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        while (getline(configurationFile, fileLine))
        {
            Line[lineCounter] = fileLine;
            DebugPrintA(Line[lineCounter].c_str());
            lineCounter++;
        }
    }
    configurationFile.close();
    return true;
}

bool assignKeys()
{
    if (Line[0] != "attack:")
    {
        string Line0 = Line[0].substr(Line[0].find(':') + 1);

        int TempLine0 = Line0.size();

        for (int a = 0; a <= TempLine0; a++)
        {
            Input[a] = Line0[a];
        }

        mapKeys();

        keys[attackKey] = Temporary;
    }
    else
    {
        keys[attackKey] = NULL;
    }

    if (Line[1] != "range:")
    {
        string Line1 = Line[1].substr(Line[1].find(':') + 1);

        if (Line1 == "melee")
        {
            rangeX = 0;
            rangeY = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            rangeX = 30;
            rangeY = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        rangeX = 0;
        rangeY = 0;
    }

    if (Line[2] != "health: ;")
    {
        string Line2Temp = Line[2];

        string Line2 = Line[2].substr(Line[2].find(':') + 1);

        int Index1 = Line2.find(';');

        if (Index1 > 0)
        {
            Line2 = Line2.substr(0, Index1);
            healthValue = atoi(Line2.c_str());
        }

        string Line22 = Line2Temp.substr(Line2Temp.find(';') + 1);

        int TempLine2 = Line22.size();

        for (int a = 0; a <= TempLine2; a++)
        {
            Input[a] = Line22[a];
        }

        mapKeys();

        keys[healthKey] = Temporary;
    }
    else
    {
        keys[healthKey] = NULL;
    }

    if (Line[3] != "mana: ;")
    {
        string Line3Temp = Line[3];

        string Line3 = Line[3].substr(Line[3].find(':') + 1);

        int Index2 = Line3.find(';');

        if (Index2 > 0)
        {
            Line3 = Line3.substr(0, Index2);
            manaValue = atoi(Line3.c_str());
        }

        string Line33 = Line3Temp.substr(Line3Temp.find(';') + 1);

        int TempLine3 = Line33.size();

        for (int a = 0; a <= TempLine3; a++)
        {
            Input[a] = Line33[a];
        }

        mapKeys();

        keys[manaKey] = Temporary;
    }
    else
    {
        keys[manaKey] = NULL;
    }

    if (Line[4] != "delay:")
    {
        string Line4 = Line[4].substr(Line[4].find(':') + 1);

        kamiDelay = atoi(Line4.c_str());
    }
    else
    {
        kamiDelay = 500;
    }

    if (keys[attackKey] != NULL && keys[healthKey] != NULL && keys[manaKey] != NULL)
    {
        Line[0].clear();
        Line[1].clear();
        Line[2].clear();
        Line[3].clear();
        Line[4].clear();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Line[0].clear();
        Line[1].clear();
        Line[2].clear();
        Line[3].clear();
        Line[4].clear();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I restate that you have a memory leak in `retrievePath`.

Comment: @chris, how would I fix this memory leak? I tested my code with commented out sections and it doesn't seem to be retrievePath afaik...

Comment: Assuming C++11, `std::string strDLLPath1; strDLLPath1.resize(MAX_PATH); GetModuleFileName(..., &strDLLPath1[0], ...);` and then you don't have to create strings from it after.

Comment: @chris, it is not the retrievePath function...I just re tested it while displaying the location more than once without crashing..thus it works perfectly fine without crashing...

Comment: How many lines are in the file?

Comment: Really need to work on a *minimal* example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Andrew, [`string Line[4];`](http://images.wikia.com/uncyclopedia/images/archive/1/13/20080321033750!Explosion.jpg)

Comment: FIXED THE CRASH, it was the the fact I had Line[4] and not Line[5]...lol god.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `assignKeys()` function you access `Line[4]`. But the `Line` array only has 4 elements, so you can only access `Line[0]` to `Line[3]` safely. Accessing `Line[4]` might crash your program.

Also if your configuration file has more than 4 lines, the statement `Line[lineCounter] = fileLine;` in `readFile()` will access elements of the `Line` array which are out of bounds. So you have to add some bounds checking to the `while` loop, too.

The better alternative probably is to use `std::vector<std::string>`. Then you could simply `push_back(...)` the elements in the `while` loop in `readFile()`. In `assignKeys()` you would have to check the size of the vector before accessing any of it's elements.

Comment: it was because I accessed Line[4]. Simple change was increase the line array.